# Bit Manipulation: Harder Flipping Coins

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Recently, I saw this problem from CodeChef titled 'Flipping Coins' (Link: [FLIPCOINS](https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLIPCOIN/)).

Summarily, there are N coins and we must write a program that supports two operations.

1. To flip coin in range [A,B]
2. To find the number of heads in range [A,B] respectively.

Of course, we can quickly use a segment tree (range query, range updates using lazy propagation) to solve this.

However, I faced another similar problem where after a series of flips (operation 1), we are required to output the resulting permutation of coins after the flips (e.g 100101, where 0 represents head while 1 represents tail).

More specifically, operation 2 changes from counting number of heads to producing the resulting permutation of all N coins. Also, the new operation 2 is **only** called after **all** the flips have been done (i.e operation 2 is the last to be called and is only called one time).

May I know how does one solve this? It requires some form of bit manipulation, according to the problem tags.

**Edit**

I attempted brute-forcing through all queries, and alas, it yield Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: Hello, can you show us what you came up yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing out the state of the coins can be done using a Binary-indexed tree:

- Initially all values are `0`.
- When we need to flip coins `[A, B]`, we increment `A` by `1` and
  decrement `B + 1` by `1`.
- The state of coin `i` is then the prefix sum at `i` modulo `2`.

This works because the prefix sum at `i` is always the number of flip operations done at `i`.

Comment: Why do you need a BIT if you're only doing increments and decrements and no range sums?

Comment: We need the prefix sum to determine the state of each coin. The prefix sum of `x` is the sum of all elements up to `x`.

Comment: But you only need to do that once, at the end (OP says "i.e operation 2 is the last to be called and is only called one time").